# Connect switch statement with imageview visibility

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

So I am trying to do a little gamble game where the player presses a button and then a image, that was invisible becomes visible again showing which picture he got.

I tried to achieve that by making a random number generator and using switch statements but my pictures wont become visible again.

This is my java file

```
package serchgoodswing.gamblegame;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public ImageView reward1;
public ImageView reward2;
public ImageView reward3;
public ImageView reward4;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



}
public void generate (View view) {
    Random rand= new Random();
    int generatedNumber = rand.nextInt(999)+1;
   switch (generatedNumber){
       case 1-500:
           reward1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           break;
       case 501-600:
           reward2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           break;
       case 601-650:
           reward3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           break;
       case 651-1000:
           reward4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           break;

   }



    }

 }
```

and this is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="serchgoodswing.caseopening.MainActivity">


<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="generate" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/a"
    android:id="@+id/reward1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/b"
    android:id="@+id/reward2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/c"
    android:id="@+id/reward3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/reward1"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/d"
    android:id="@+id/reward4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/reward2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

What did I wrong? Someone has a solution for it?

Comment: What do you think `case 1-500` mean and why?

Comment: Im new at java so my code will definitly have some faults. I thought that case 1-500 will check if the generated number is in the range of 1 to 500 and if it's the case it will set ImageView visible again but now that you asked I assume that it means something else?

Comment: @PM77-1 I forgot to mention your name but can't edit my comment.

Comment: `1-500` is evaluated to `-499`. You have not answered the 2nd part of my question: why did you think that `case` syntax supports ranges? Where did you see such syntax for [`switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using a different value for the cases. Java does not like ranges for switch statements. There are several ways to get around this, but one simple solution would be to use if statements to compare your ranges to the generated random number.

```
int result;
if(generatedNumber >=1 && generatedNumber <= 500)
     result = 1;
if(generatedNumber >=501 && generatedNumber <= 600)
     result = 2;
if(generatedNumber >=601 && generatedNumber <= 650)
     result = 3;
if(generatedNumber >=651 && generatedNumber <= 1000)
     result = 4;
```

Then change your switch statement to use the result variable versus the generatedNumber (range) you currently have.

You could also just add logic to the if statements and skip the switch statements altogether.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking but what do you mean by use the result variable versus the generated?

Comment: public void generate (View view) {
            Random rand= new Random();
            int generatedNumber = rand.nextInt(999)+1;
            switch (result){
               case 1:
                   reward1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   break;
               case 2:
                   reward2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   break;
               case 3:
                   reward3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   break;
               case 4:
                   reward4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   break;

Comment: Sorry, the formatting for the code is not right. At any rate just swap out in your code result where you have the switch using generatedNumber. Then change the cases to use 1, 2, 3, 4 instead of the ranges.